# Trying to prevent multiple form entries with identical field data (only allow first user to take timeslot)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to have users enter data in a django form and only allow ONE entry into the database per each time slot and day slot.

Example: User fills out form to "sign up" to speak during 8:00am - 9:00am on Day 1 for schedule id 2.

If a database entry already exists with the same TIMESLOT and DAYSLOT, I want to raise an error and prevent entry.

Here is what I have so far, but the filter is spanning across the entire table rather than just filtering per schedule ID...

```
models.py

from django.db import models
import datetime

class Schedule(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Agenda(models.Model):

    dayChoice = (
     ('d1', "Day 1"),
     ('d2', "Day 2"),
     ('d3', "Day 3"),
     ('d4', "Day 4")
    )

    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    startTime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    endTime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    daySlot = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=dayChoice)
    sub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    scheduler = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullName
```

---

```
   views.py
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from .models import Schedule, Agenda
    from .forms import AgendaForm
    # Create your views here.

    def schedule_list(request):
        schedules = Schedule.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'adjenda/schedule_list.html', {'schedules': schedules})

    def agenda_detail(request, pk):
        schedules = get_object_or_404(Schedule, pk=pk)
        agenda = Agenda.objects.filter(scheduler_id=pk).order_by('startTime')
        form = AgendaForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AgendaForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.published_date = timezone.now()
                post.save()
                return redirect("/schedule/" + pk)
        else:
            form = AgendaForm()

        return render(request, 'adjenda/schedule_detail.html', {'agenda': agenda, 'schedules': schedules, 'form': form})


forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Agenda, Schedule

class AgendaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Agenda
        fields = '__all__'



    def clean_startTime(self):
        startTime = self.cleaned_data['startTime']
        if Agenda.objects.filter(startTime=startTime).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Time/Day already taken")
        return startTime
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together) is what you're looking for:

```
class Agenda(models.Model):
    # field definiton

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("startTime", "endTime", "daySlot")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I also added "scheduler" as a parameter and worked perfectly. Thanks so much Guillermo, you rock!

Comment: I need this as well, where do you add unique_together?  The documentation isn't to helpful with that.

Comment: @student101 add it into your models.py below the model class that houses the fields you want to include in unique_together.

Comment: As a new field??